# What is the minimum value of $X= (a+2b +3c+...)$, given $X - ( a+b+c+...) \ge N$, where all variables $\ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Given $X= (a+2b +3c+...)$, i.e this pattern sum of a set of $i$ variables.

And $Y = ( a+b+c+...)$, i.e the sum of the same set of $i$ variables,

given the  constraint 
 $X - Y\ge N$, where $N$ is a positive number,

Find the minimum value of $ X$. All variables are greater or equal to zero.

I am tempted to say:
$X = N +Y$ , so when $Y = 0$ then the
Minimum value of $X$ is $ N$.
 But if Y is zero then all of $a,b,c...$ will all be zero and so  $X -Y$ will no longer be greater or equal to $N$.

Is there an intuitive way to find the minimum value of X, or at least express it as a  linear sum of $a,b,c...?$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $X=a+2b+3c+\cdots+i\,z$ ($i$ terms) to minimise and $b+2c+\cdots + (i-1)\,z\geqslant N$, it is immediate that this is an L.P. So the minimum is at one of the corners bounded by the hyper plane $b+2c+\cdots +(i-1)\,z=N$ and the axes - where except one all other variables are $0$.  Suppose the $k$th variable, say $\alpha$, is non-zero, then we have
$$(k-1)\alpha =N \implies X = k\,\alpha=\frac{k}{k-1}N$$
As this is decreasing in $k$, we must have the last variable non-zero, to get a minimum of $X_{min}=\frac{i}{i-1}N$.